# Hive column transpose

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 5 columns in a table in hive as shown below:

```
5314|43045.9637152778   0       app_3   1       app_other
5314|43045.9637152778   0       app_9   1       app_other
5314|43045.9637152778   0       app_18  1       app_other
5314|43045.9637152778   0       app_2   1       app_other
5314|43045.9637152778   0       app_12  1       app_other
```

I would like to convert the above data into the following output with headers:

```
id                      app_3   app_9   app_18  app_2   app_12  app_other
5314|43045.9637152778   0       0       0       0       0       1
```

I want to col3 value as column name and respective col2 value as value of col3. Could you please help me on how do we do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer please about column transpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099098/2700344

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772741/2700344

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770081/2700344 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772741/2700344

Comment: Possible duplicate of [impala transpose column to row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098917/impala-transpose-column-to-row)